# Adding PHP zip extension in a Docker image

Tags: php, docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to install the Zip extension of my PHP container built from `php:7.4-fpm-alpine`

This is what I am using in my *Dockerfile*

```bash
RUN apk add --no-cache zip libzip-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip=/usr/include
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
```

But it is giving me this error:

> configure: error: unrecognized options: --with-libzip ERROR: Service
> 'php' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c
> docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip=/usr/include' returned a
> non-zero code: 1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The solution is as simple as removing the `docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip` line entirely for PHP >= 7.4. Defaults are sufficient.

<sup>*As commented by [hackel](https://github.com/hackel) on their issue tracker: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/2421#issuecomment-567728540*</sup>

So a working *Dockerfile* would be:

```sh
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
      libzip-dev \
      zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sh
FROM composer AS composer

COPY . /app
RUN rm composer.lock && composer install \
  --optimize-autoloader \
  --no-interaction \
  --no-progress \
  --ignore-platform-reqs


RUN apk add --no-cache php \
    php7-common \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-zip \
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if using php:7.4-fpm

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y zip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
```